# Using nltk to analyze a random document based on reading a given document

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I am relatively new to this, so I am not sure if this is correct.  I would like to analyze a document based on another document I have analyzed.

This is what I have so far.

```
import nltk
sent_one = "Here is a sentence I would like to break up into words"
sent_two = "This is new.  How is the weather up there?"
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sent_one)
tokens_two = nltk.word.tokenize(sent_two)
new_set = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
second_set = nltk.pos_tag(tokens_two)

t0 = nltk.DefaultTagger('NN') 
t1 = nltk.UnigramTagger(new_set, backoff = t0) 
t2 = nltk.BigramTagger(new_set, backoff = t1)
t2.evaluate(tokens_two)
```

This is the error that I get 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
in   t1 = nltk.UnigramTagger(new_set, backoff = t0)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

I want to use this to analyze sent_two I understand that this means that the UnigramTagger is unable to recognize sent_one as a list of words/parts of speech, but I am not sure how to correct this.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/alvations/spaghetti-tagger

Comment: @alvas Thanks for the info.  So this is built on the CESS corpus. But the link in the article is no longer available, so I cannot see how they have built it.